# How to apply validation inside iterator tag in sturts2

Tags: java, struts2

I'm trying to apply form validation in struts2 inside iterator tag.
In the below jsp page when account number is added to the search textfield then the iterator tag loads the current data of that account number, where the details can be edited. After the edits when submit is clicked I want that validation should applied to the textfields inside the iterator tag so wrong type off data is not entered.

*Note: No ajax just Struts2 validation by any means.

Jsp page (edituserdetails.jsp):

```
                <s:form action="editUserDetails">
                    <h1><s:text name="Edit User Details"/></h1>
                    <h2><s:property value="successmsz"/></h2>
                    <s:textfield key="accountno_check" label="Enter Account No."/>
                    <s:submit key="submitreq" value="Search" cssClass="button_bt"/>

                    <s:iterator value="ubb">

                        <s:textfield key="accountno" label="Account No." readonly="true"/>
                        <s:textfield key="aadhar"  label="Enter Aadhar number"/>
                        <s:textfield key="pan" label="Enter PAN number"/>
                        <s:textfield key="name" label="Enter name"/>
                        <s:textfield key="age" label="Enter age" />
                        <s:radio key="gender" label="Gender" list="#{'Male':'Male'}"/>
                        <s:radio key="gender" label="Gender" list="#{'Female':'Female'}"/>
                        <s:radio key="gender" label="Gender" list="#{'Other':'Other'}"/>
                        <s:textfield key="mobile" label="Enter Mobile No."/>
                        <s:textfield key="landline" label="Enter Landline No."/>
                        <s:textfield key="father" label="Enter Father name"/>
                        <s:textfield key="address" label="Enter current Address"/>
                        <s:textfield key="p_address" label="Enter permanent Address"/>
                        <s:textfield key="country" label="Enter Country"/>

                        <s:select label="Select Account Type" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Account Type" 
                                  list="#{'Saving':'Saving','Current':'Current'}" key="account_type"/>
                        <br/>
                        <div style="width: 450px;">
                            <s:submit value="Submit" key="submitreq" cssClass="button_bt"/>
                        </div>

                    </s:iterator>
                </s:form>
```

Action support based action (EditUserDetails.java):

```
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        HibernateOperation op = new HibernateOperation();
        UserBean ub = new UserBean();
        if (submitreq.equalsIgnoreCase("submit")) {

            ub.setAccountno(accountno);
            ub.setAadhar(aadhar);
            ub.setPan(pan);
            ub.setName(name);
            ub.setAge(age);
            ub.setGender(gender);
            ub.setMobile(mobile);
            ub.setLandline(landline);
            ub.setFather(father);
            ub.setAddress(address);
            ub.setP_address(p_address);
            ub.setCountry(country);
            ub.setAccount_type(account_type);



            boolean b = op.updateUserDetails(ub);  // Updating details
            if (b) {
                ubb = op.getUserBalance(accountno);  //Getting user details for further output
                return LOGIN;
            } else {

                return ERROR;
            }
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Into Searching of account number");
            ubb = op.getUserBalance(accountno_check);  //Searching account number details

            if (ubb.size() > 0) {
                return SUCCESS;
            } else {

                return NONE;
            }
        }
    }

    public void validate()
    {
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(aadhar))
                addFieldError("aadhar", "Aadhar number cannot be blank");
    }

}
```

Struts2 configuration file:

```
<action name="editUserDetails" class="example.EditUserDetails">
            <result name="success">edituserinfo.jsp</result>
            <result name="none">edituserinfo.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">employeecontrolpanel.jsp</result>
            <result name="login">userbalancesheet.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">edituserinfo.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you reduced your code to a minimal example

Comment: @madmuffin I have reduced the code, see if it helps and feel free to ask for further changes.